# CodeIgniter Message: Undefined property: Member_model::$db

Tags: php, codeigniter

In my autoload.php file

```
$autoload['libraries'] = array('database', 'session');
```

Member Controller:

```
Class Member extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {        
        parent::__construct();
    }

    public function index()
    {

    }

    public function login()
    {
        $this->load->model('admin/member_model', 'member_model');

        $username = $this->input->get('username');
        $password = $this->input->get('password');

        $this->member_model->__set('username', $username);
        $this->member_model->__set('password', $password);

        $this->member_model->login();
    }
}
```

And my Member_model.php

```
Class Member_model extends CI_Model
{
    var $id;
    var $username;
    var $password;
    var $email;
    var $type;

    public function __set($name, $value)
    {
        $this->{$name} = $value;
    }

    public function __get($name)
    {
        return $this->{$name};
    }

    public function login()
    {
        $this->db->get('username');
    }
}
```

But when I call `login` method of `member_model`,  CodeIgniter returns the following error:

> A PHP Error was encountered
>
> Severity: Notice
>
> Message: Undefined property: Member_model::$db
>
> Filename: admin/member_model.php
>
> Line Number: 17

I want to know what I'm doing wrong and how to fix it

Comment: A model needs to be tied to a database, you're loading the database library, but have you configured a connection?

Comment: Yes, I connected to database.

Answer (score 0):

```
Class Member_model extends CI_Model
    {
        var $id;
        var $username;
        var $password;
        var $email;
        var $type;
        var $db;
        public function setDb($db){
           $this->db = $db;
        }

        public function __set($name, $value)
        {
            $this->{$name} = $value;
        }

        public function __get($name)
        {
            return $this->{$name};
        }

        public function login()
        {
            $this->db->get('username');
        }
    }

$memberModel = new Member_model();
$memberModel ->setDb($db);
.......
$memberModel->login()
```

OR

```
Class Member_model extends CI_Model
        {
            var $id;
            var $username;
            var $password;
            var $email;
            var $type;
            var $db;
            public function __constructor($db, ..... some other params....){
               $this->db = $db;
               parent::__construct(..... some other params....);
            }

            public function __set($name, $value)
            {
                $this->{$name} = $value;
            }

            public function __get($name)
            {
                return $this->{$name};
            }

            public function login()
            {
                $this->db->get('username');
            }
        }

    $memberModel = new Member_model($db);

    .......
    $memberModel->login()
```